# Why doesn't my object's property update in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a function, which I have prepared for a *constructor call*...

```
function Queue() {
  if (!(this instanceof Queue)) return new Queue();
    this.capacity = {};
    this._count = 0;
}
```

And these method are being set on the the prototype property of `Queue`...Everything kosher right?

```
  Queue.prototype.enqueue = function(name, options) {
    this.capacity[name] = options || {};
    this.count();
    if (this._count > 5) {
      return 'Max capacity has been reached—which is five, please dequeue....'
    }
  };

  Queue.prototype.count = function() {
    var total = Object.keys(this.capacity);
      total.forEach(function(elem) {
        this._count++
      });
      if (this._count == 1) {
        console.log(this.capacity[Object.keys(this.capacity)])
      console.log( 'There is one item in the queue');
      } else {
        console.log(this.capacity[Object.keys(this.capacity)])
        console.log( 'There are ' + this._count + ' items in the queue');
      }
   };
```

My question how do i get `this._count` to increment when the enqueue/count method fires? I keep getting:

```
There are 0 items in the queue
```

I know I could add it on the `.prototype` property and place that in the count function and have it reference a local var...

```
Queue.prototype.count = function() {
    var total = Object.keys(this.capacity), count = 0;
    total.forEach(function(elem) {
      this.count++
    });
```

Queue.prototype.call = call // <-- weird no?

```
if (this.count == 1) {
    console.log(this.capacity[Object.keys(this.capacity)])
  console.log( 'There is one item in the queue');
} else {
     console.log(this.capacity[Object.keys(this.capacity)])
  console.log( 'There are ' + this.count + ' items in the queue');
}
```

};

But that seems not to be elegant...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could simplify to `this._count += Object.keys(this.capacity).length`. And didn't you mean to reset `_count` to zero or use `=` instead of `+=`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind this within forEach

```
Queue.prototype.count = function() {
    var total = Object.keys(this.capacity);
      total.forEach(function(elem) {
        this._count++
      }.bind(this)); //bind the context
      if (this._count == 1) {
        console.log(this.capacity[Object.keys(this.capacity)])
      console.log( 'There is one item in the queue');
      } else {
        console.log(this.capacity[Object.keys(this.capacity)])
        console.log( 'There are ' + this._count + ' items in the queue');
      }
   };
```

Comment: or use an arrow function with lexical this binding or simply do the outdated `var self = this;` and use `self` within the callback.

Comment: Agreed. There are lot of solutions. But my guess is the user wants the solution to work in IE10 , IE 11. Other wise he would have used ES6 syntax everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try following modification (bind the function):

```
total.forEach(function(elem) {
   this._count++
}.bind(this));
```

The problems is that `this` refers to a different object than in the parent function, because in JS, closures do not preserve `this` but instead the caller decides the `this` value. Alternatively, you can use the second `thisArg` argument of foreach.

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers provide good solutions to the problem itself, I just thought I'd elaborate a bit more on the why.

`this` is a reference assigned by the execution context. More plainly it's a reference that's determined by the call site of the function. Since you can pass functions around in JavaScript like any other value this can lead to problems being caused by that reference being a moving target.

The issue with your code is that you're referring to `this` inside of a `forEach`. `forEach` takes a function as an argument and calls it, since what `this` is pointing to is determined by where the function is called and not where it's defined the value is something different when it gets called. It ends up falling back to whatever global context or undefined if you're in strict mode.

There are a number of different ways to handle the problem.

You could store a reference to the outer `this` on a variable and use it inside the other function.

```
var self = this;
total.forEach(function(elem) {
  self._count++;
});
```

You could use `.bind`. It's a function method which returns a function that uses the passed in object as the reference for `this` no matter where you call it.

```
total.forEach(function(elem) {
  this._count++;
}.bind(this));
```

Or you could use an arrow function. Arrow functions don't create their own context so they'll just maintain the value of `this` from the surrounding one.

```
total.forEach(() => {
  this._count++;
});
```

This is a common problem and these are all valid solutions. They go from least to most elegant in my opinion.